# Как добавить в массив только checkbox'ы с checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть пустой массив (`var arr = [];`).

Есть множество checkbox'ов с одинаковым классом (можно перебирать через цикл).

Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы если checkbox активный, то он добавляется в массив; если нет - он удаляется из массива. Мне важно, чтобы `arr.length === количество активных checkbox'ов`. События происходит при клике на checkbox'ы.

Вот код, который следит за изменением. Но тут немного другой функционал.

```
$( 'input.sl-chb' ).on( 'click', function() {
  $( '#cityList' ).html( $('input:checked' ).val() );
  if(TextCity.innerHTML == 'Был выбран undefined'){
    TextCity.innerHTML = 'Выберите город';
  }
});
```

Тут отображается только один. Мне нужен массив для того, чтобы делать условия, мол если длина массива больше двух, то `.html('Выбрано городов : ' + arr.length;)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

что-то такое ?

```js
$('input.sl-chb').on('click', function() {
  $('#cityList').html($('input.sl-chb:checked').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" />

<div id="cityList"></div>
```

Ваш массив, в данном случае, это `$('input.sl-chb:checked')`, то есть просто выборка всех `input:checked`.

Answer (score 1):

А как вам такое на "ваниле"?

```js
var arr = [];
var checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('.sl-chb');

checkboxs.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.onclick = () => {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sl-chb:checked');
    var arr = [].map.call(elems, function(obj) {
      return obj.value;
    });
    console.log(arr);
  }
})
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" value='oдин' />один</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" value='два' />два</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" value='три' />три</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" value='черыре' />черыре</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" value='пять' />пять</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="sl-chb" value='шесть' />шесть</label><br>
```

Comment: Неплохо, неплохо... +1